# How do you serve a single directory with Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a directory containing files: `/Users/Dave/MyFolder/`

How would I configure Apache so I can access files in it, specifically with this root URL:  `http://127.0.0.1/Users/Dave/MyFolder/...`

I understand permissions on files must allow everyone read-access. This is a one-off directory (e.g. I don't want to break what's already at `/var/www/`).

Comment: Users directory not being under /var/www in this case?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mod_alias` and the `Alias` directive - full details at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias, but basically `Alias /http/path /fs/path`